# Connection between two Indy UDP Servers

Tags: udp, c++builder, indy

I'm using RAD Studio 10.2 with two instances of `TIdUDPServer` from Indy 10.

I run my program on Windows 10 and check the counters of sent and received packages, but there are no packages received. At the same time, I see through Wireshark that they come to the PC, but the second `TIdUDPServer` does not receive the packages. Why?

Here is my code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

typedef struct {
    char Data[10000];
} struct_Buffer;

int i = 0;
int n = 0;
int k = 0;
int TxSize = 1400;
char TxData;
struct_Buffer TxBuffer;

AnsiString ServerIP1 = "192.168.10.1";
AnsiString ServerIP2 = "192.168.10.2";
TBytes Buffer;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TMyQueueProc1 : public TCppInterfacedObject<TThreadProcedure>
{
private:
    int m_counter;
    TIdBytes m_bytes;

public:
    TMyQueueProc1(int ACounter, const TIdBytes &AData) : m_counter(ACounter), m_bytes(AData) {}
    INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);

    void __fastcall Invoke()
    {
        Form1->Label1->Caption = "Rx " + IntToStr(m_counter);
    }
};

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    try {
        TIdSocketHandle *SocketHandle_Server = Form1->IdUDPServer1->Bindings->Add();
        SocketHandle_Server->IP = ServerIP1;
        SocketHandle_Server->Port = 4004;
        Form1->IdUDPServer1->Active = true;
    }
    catch(Exception *ex) {
        ShowMessage("IdUDPServer1 start error!");
    }

    try {
        TIdSocketHandle *SocketHandle_Echo = Form1->IdUDPServer2->Bindings->Add();
        SocketHandle_Echo->IP = ServerIP2;
        SocketHandle_Echo->Port = 4004;
        Form1->IdUDPServer2->Active = true;
    }
    catch(Exception *ex) {
        ShowMessage("IdUDPServer2 start error!");
    }

    Timer1->Interval = 100;
    Timer1->Enabled = true;

    Label3->Caption = "IdUPDServer1: " + ServerIP1;
    Label4->Caption = "IdUDPServer2: " + ServerIP2;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    TxData++;
    if (TxData == 255) TxData = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < TxSize; k++) TxBuffer.Data[k] = TxData;

    Buffer = RawToBytes(&TxBuffer.Data[0], TxSize);
    Form1->IdUDPServer1->SendBuffer(ServerIP2, 4004, Buffer);

    n++;
    Label2->Caption = "Tx " + IntToStr(n);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdUDPServer2UDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, const TIdBytes AData,
          TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    i++;
    TThread::Queue(NULL, _di_TThreadProcedure(new TMyQueueProc1(i, AData)));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to catch exception objects by reference, not by pointer. And your use of `TThread::Queue()` is unnecessary if `TIdUDPServer::ThreadedEvent` is false (which it is by default).   Besides that, I don't see anything else wrong with this code, so the most obvious question is - do you have `IdUDPServer2UDPRead` assigned to `IdUDPServer2` to begin with?

Comment: Yes, i turned on `TIdUDPServer::ThreadedEvent` and method `IdUDPServer2UDPRead ` assigned to `IdUDPServer2`. If I set up local IPs `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.2`, then everything starts working. I dont understand...

Comment: [127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 are on the same adapter/interface](https://superuser.com/questions/393700/), so there is a route between them. Are 192.168.10.1 and 192.168.10.2 real IPs assigned to your PC, connected to the same network, or at least have a route between them?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, i have two Ethernet adapters with these IPs on PC. They connected with two cables to router and through Wireshark i see that UDP packets come back to PC, but I dont see that in my program.

Comment: did you verify with `netstat` that your app is actually bound and listening on both IPs? Did you check whether `OnUDPRead` is actually being called and your UI is just not being updating?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found the answer to my question experimentally. If the same ports 4004 are installed on the IP `192.168.10.1` and `192.168.10.2`, then there is no data reception in the program, although the exchange goes. Once I just put different ports, the reception began. Network adapters are built into the PC motherboard. Could you explain why this happened?

Comment: no. Maybe faulty hardware, or faulty drivers.